How to select an existing custom goal when creating campaign
I want to create a campaign through the Google Ads API. And I've successfully created a campaign. But when I compared it with the UI created one, I realized that I didn't choose a custom goal. In the UI I'll set it up like this.
enter image description here
I can get all the custom goals via GAQL.
SELECT 
  custom_conversion_goal.resource_name, 
  custom_conversion_goal.id, 
  custom_conversion_goal.name, 
  custom_conversion_goal.conversion_actions, 
  custom_conversion_goal.status, 
  customer.id 
FROM custom_conversion_goal 
WHERE custom_conversion_goal.name='xxx'

This is shown in the figure below.enter image description here
Now, I want to select the custom goal from the query while creating a campaign using google ads api.How should I write my python code?
Reference document link
Also, I've attached the sample code for the base campaign that I've successfully created, it's not much different from what's in the documentation.
import sys

from google.ads.googleads.client import GoogleAdsClient
from google.ads.googleads.errors import GoogleAdsException

_DATE_FORMAT = "%Y%m%d"


def handle_googleads_exception(exception):
    print(
        f'Request with ID "{exception.request_id}" failed with status '
        f'"{exception.error.code().name}" and includes the following errors:'
    )
    for error in exception.failure.errors:
        print(f'\tError with message "{error.message}".')
        if error.location:
            for field_path_element in error.location.field_path_elements:
                print(f"\t\tOn field: {field_path_element.field_name}")
    sys.exit(1)


def create_campaign(client, customer_id):
    campaign_budget_service = client.get_service("CampaignBudgetService")
    campaign_service = client.get_service("CampaignService")

    campaign_budget_operation = client.get_type("CampaignBudgetOperation")
    campaign_budget = campaign_budget_operation.create
    ampaign_budget.amount_micros = 50000000
    campaign_budget.explicitly_shared = False

    campaign_budget_response = None
    try:
        campaign_budget_response = campaign_budget_service.mutate_campaign_budgets(
            customer_id=customer_id, operations=[campaign_budget_operation]
        )
    except GoogleAdsException as e:
        handle_googleads_exception(e)

    campaign_operation = client.get_type("CampaignOperation")
    campaign = campaign_operation.create
    campaign.name = 'campaign-test1'
    campaign.status = client.enums.CampaignStatusEnum.PAUSED

campaign.tracking_url_template = "{...}"
    campaign.advertising_channel_type = client.enums.AdvertisingChannelTypeEnum.DISPLAY
    campaign.targeting_setting.target_restrictions.targeting_dimension = client.enums.TargetingDimensionEnum.AUDIENCE
    campaign.targeting_setting.target_restrictions.bid_only = False
    campaign.audience_setting.use_audience_grouped = False
    campaign.geo_target_type_setting.positive_geo_target_type = client.enums.PositiveGeoTargetTypeEnum.PRESENCE
    campaign.geo_target_type_setting.negative_geo_target_type = client.enums.NegativeGeoTargetTypeEnum.PRESENCE

    campaign.target_cpa.target_cpa_micros = 100000

    campaign.campaign_budget = campaign_budget_response.results[0].resource_name

    # Setting the specified custom goal but with an error
    # AttributeError: Unknown field for Campaign: conversion_goal_campaign_config
    campaign.conversion_goal_campaign_config.custom_conversion_goal = "customers/xxxx/customConversionGoals/xxxxx"

    try:
        campaign_response = campaign_service.mutate_campaigns(
            customer_id=customer_id, operations=[campaign_operation]
        )
        print(f"Created campaign {campaign_response.results[0].resource_name}.")
    except GoogleAdsException as ex:
        handle_googleads_exception(ex)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    googleads_client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage(
        path=r"./google-ads-th.yaml",
        version="v17"
    )
    customer_id = "xxxx"

    create_campaign(googleads_client, customer_id)


I never found in the documentation how to select a custom goal when creating campaign.and I had to specify the campaign type as DISPLAY. It can't be a performance max campaign or an app campaign. Both campaigns can specify a custom goal. Because it is clearly stated in the documentation.

Can anyone help me? I've been stuck for a week.
